# Do root relative link urls work in amp html when site cached?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, amp-html

I have a amp-only website and all links are root relative like below:

```
<a href="/page-2/detail" />
```

Do link urls work when site cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they do. You can easily verify by manually loading your page (or a test page) from the AMP cache. [Here is a guide (and a tool)](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/guides/using_the_google_amp_cache/#amp-cache-url-format) on how to construct the AMP Cache URLs.